# Ansible aws network load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, boto3, nlb

Is there a way to use Ansible to create a Network Load Balance in AWS?
There is a module for Application LB but not for NLB. Is it possible to use Boto3 to do it?

Answer (score 0):

## Create Network Load Balancer via Boto3

Network Load Balancers (NLBs) and Applicataion Load Balancers (ALB) are both classified under Elastic Load Balancing V2 in the CLI and SDKs. This is because they have different underlying API compared to the Classic Load Balancers (ELB).

Creating NLBs using boto3 would, therefore, fall under the elbv2 client:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('elbv2')
client.create_load_balancer(Name='my-load-balancer', Type='network')
```

For more info check the [boto3 docs for elbv2](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/elbv2.html?highlight=loadbalancingv2#ElasticLoadBalancingv2.Client.create_load_balancer).

## Provisioning a Load Balancer via Ansible

The Ansible [elb_application_lb](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/elb_application_lb_module.html) doesn't seem to support the `type` key as an input. As a workaround, I would suggest using the Ansible [cloudFormation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.3/cloudformation_module.html) module to provision the load balancer.

### CloudFormation Template - `my-nlb-stack.yml`

```
Resources:
  NetworkLoadBalancer:
    Type: "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer"
    Properties:
      Name: my-network-lb
      Type: network
      Subnets:
        - subnet-aabbccdd
        - subnet-ddeeff11
        - subnet-22334455
Outputs:
  MyNLB:
    Description: The ARN of the newly provisioned NLB
    Value: !Ref NetworkLoadBalancer
```

### Ansible Playbook - `playbook.yml`

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: launch ansible network lb stack with cloudformation
      cloudformation:
        stack_name: MyNetworkLBStack
        state: present
        region: eu-west-1
        template: my-lb-stack.yml
      register: nlbstack
    - name: check the facts of the load balancer
      elb_application_lb_facts:
        load_balancer_arns:
          - "{{ nlbstack.stack_outputs.MyNLB }}"
```

Once the stack has provisioned, you'll be able to use the application load balancer modules against the NLB with no problems.

Comment: Thanks Jason, but I need to use the information from the NLB creation for my next steps - attach listeners and EIP. I assume from your answer that this information will not be available nor would I know when its ready. Isn't there a "pure Ansible" way to do it (the same way as application LB is working?

Comment: Additionally, at some place I saw an example like this: 
`- name: Create/Update NLB
    aws:
      profile: "{{ boto_profile }}"
      region: "{{ ec2_region }}"
      service: elbv2
      method:  create_load_balancer
      params:
        Name: "myNLB"
        Type: network
        Subnets:
        - "{{ ec2_slice1_private_subnet }}"
        - "{{ ec2_slice2_private_subnet }}"
        - "{{ ec2_slice3_private_subnet }}"
        Scheme: "internal"
        IpAddressType: "ipv4"` 
But this is now working for me. maybe it's a solution but I'm missing how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to use the module `elb_network_lb` as shown below:

## Create an ELB and attach a listener

```
- elb_network_lb:
    name: myelb
    subnets:
      - subnet-012345678
      - subnet-abcdef000
    listeners:
      - Protocol: TCP # Required. The protocol for connections from clients to the load balancer (Only TCP is available) (case-sensitive).
        Port: 80 # Required. The port on which the load balancer is listening.
        DefaultActions:
          - Type: forward # Required. Only 'forward' is accepted at this time
            TargetGroupName: mytargetgroup # Required. The name of the target group
    state: present
```

## Create an ELB with an attached Elastic IP address

```
- elb_network_lb:
    name: myelb
    subnet_mappings:
      - SubnetId: subnet-012345678
        AllocationId: eipalloc-aabbccdd
    listeners:
      - Protocol: TCP # Required. The protocol for connections from clients to the load balancer (Only TCP is available) (case-sensitive).
        Port: 80 # Required. The port on which the load balancer is listening.
        DefaultActions:
          - Type: forward # Required. Only 'forward' is accepted at this time
            TargetGroupName: mytargetgroup # Required. The name of the target group
    state: present
```

## Remove an ELB

```
- elb_network_lb:
    name: myelb
    state: absent
```